# Multiple textile sources for single html page in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, textile

I have a Jekyll site, made in textile, which is very big and would like to separate it in several source pages.

The `include` tag seems to only work for html pages.

An alternative would be to run a script that would merge the several pages before jekyll converts the textile to html.

Can this be done?

Comment: Your question is not clear to me, but have you tried this: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-textile-converter

Comment: What part is not clear?
Yes, I have the converter from textile to html, but I would like to separate the textile "code" in several files, and this only seems to allow for one textile file for each html page.

Comment: Can you show your repo? That will probably help us to understand and help.

Comment: Example: You should be able to include any filetype (,html,.css, .scss, .textile) from any text file (,html,.css, .scss, .textile) provided it has the front matter in it. Include is a liquid tag - which does processing. The include should work. As said, seeing code would likely be easier to understand what has been done. Hopefully we can then help.

Comment: @TBB You are correct. From the documentation (https://jekyllrb.com/docs/includes/) I got the wrong idea that only html files could be included (i.e., included files would not be parsed). After testing I realize I was wrong.